# Potential reasons for AWS instance crashing

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've had an AWS instance running a web & mail server for 6 months. It crashes often, about once per week. It usually takes 15 mins - 2 hours before the server is up again. One time I contacted Amazon about this and they gave me a stock response which essentially said it was a hardware failure. I don't believe my instance runs into hardware failures once a week.

**What steps should I take to find out why my instance has so much downtime?**

Answer (score 1):

The hardware issue is with the AWS hypervisor that runs your instance and many other instances.

> You need to stop your instance and wait until it shows as stopped on your console then start it again.

This will make your instance run on another hypervisor. AWS is randomly moving your instances to another hardware when you start it.

This should fix your issue.